# Use innerHTML to reload the center pane of the page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Instead of using the iframe, I want to use the following method to update the center pane of the page.

I would like to get some help on the following.
If have another HTML page I want to load into the center pane, what would be the right syntax for it?

```
document.getElementById( 'centerPane' ).innerHTML.??? = 'SampleHTML.htm' ;
```

What attribute do I need to get after innerHTML?

Or should I do it using some other calls.

Comment: You need AJAX here. Try jQuery's AJAX calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using jQuery or another library with built in ajax methods:

```
var setHtml = function (element, url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            element.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhr.timeout = 10000;
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

Then simply call the setHtml function like this:

```
setHtml(document.getElementById('centerPane'), 'SampleHTML.htm');
```

Comment: There's an error in syntax. It's should be `setHtml(document.getElementById('centerPane'), 'SampleHTML.htm');`

Comment: Google debugger showed an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (repeated 2 times)." error right after  this line "element.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;"
 function UpdateCenterPane(dest) {
  var setHtml = function(element, url) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     element.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
   };
   xhr.timeout = 10000;
   xhr.open('GET', url, true);
   xhr.send();
  };
  setHtml(dojo.byId('centerPane'),dest);
 }

Comment: This is because the element is null.  Check the dojo.byId('centerPane') and make sure that it is returning an element and not null.

Answer (score 3):

If you are by any chance using jQuery, it can be as simple as:

$('#centerPage').load('SampleHTML.htm');

Comment: I hope he's using jQuery, otherwise he'll likely have to go piece together an XHR object manually.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses...I am not using jQuery. I am using html/dojo.  The data in the center pane is rendered through a dojox.grid.DataGrid.  Any more suggestions? Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax to do do this. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wGw9X/1/

You could (should) also use jQuery to simplify it and make it more cross browser compilant. In jquery it would be just one row of code.

EDIT: Updated jsfiddle link to use a better example loading file.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses...I am not using jQuery. I am using html/dojo. The data in the center pane is rendered through a dojox.grid.DataGrid. I use dojox.data.JsonRestStore to get the data and then render it vai DataGrid. How do I do this via jQuery?  Any more suggestions? Thanks again.